# What would be a good way to get newly submitted JSON data via ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

When a user enters a number and clicks submit, it's sent to a url which updates my JSON page with the current number. I want to be able to display the current number without having to refresh the page at all. Is there an easy way to do this possibly using an ajax call? Below it shows the code for getting games and the data I need but I want to be able to pull that same data when the user submits so that it updates.

```
getGames().done(function(results){
        $.each(results, function (i, gameData){
            $.each(gameData, function(key, game){

                var gamesHome = game.home_team_conference;
                var gamesAway = game.away_team_conference;


                if(gamesHome == "Big 12" || gamesAway == "Big 12"){

                    var gameId = game.id;
                    var homeTeam = game.home_team.market;
                    var awayTeam = game.away_team.market;
                    var pointTotal = game.total_points_bet;
                    var gameTime = game.game_time_hour;
                    var gameDate = game.game_time_date;
                    var homeId = game.home_team.id;
                    var awayId = game.away_team.id;
                    var network = game.broadcast_network;
                    var homePoints = game.total_points_bet_on_hometeam;
                    var awayPoints = game.total_points_bet_on_awayteam;
                    var totalPoints = homePoints + awayPoints;
                    var hue = 'rgb(' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ')';
                    var hueTwo = 'rgb(' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ')';


                $('.wrapper').append('\
                    <div id="'+ gameId +'" class="main-wrapper col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">\
                    <div class="game-cards">\
                    <div class="chart-container">\
                    <canvas id="'+ homeTeam +'" width="500" height="500"></canvas>\
                    </div>\
                    <div class="right-info">\
                    <h4>' + awayTeam + '<br>' + " @ " + '<br>' + homeTeam +'</h4>\
                    <h5 id="time-channel">'+ gameDate +' @ ' + gameTime  + '<br>' + ' On ' + network +'</h5>\
                    <div class="total-points-live">\
                    <h5>Total Points Bet</h5>\
                    <h5 id="point-total">'+ totalPoints +'</h5>\
                    <p>'+ awayTeam +'</p>\
                    <input class="bet-input-away" data-away-id="'+ awayId +'" data-team-type="'+ awayTeam +'" type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" name="betAmountAway" placeholder="Wager Amount">\
                    <p>'+ homeTeam +'</p>\
                    <input class="bet-input-home" data-home-id="'+ homeId +'" data-team-type="'+ homeTeam +'" type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" name="betAmountHome" placeholder="Wager Amount">\
                    <p class="bet-button" gameid="'+ gameId +'">Click To Place Bet</p>\
                    </div>\
                    </div>\
                    </div>\
                    ');


                $('.bet-input-away').on('input', function() {
                   if($(this).val().length)
                      $('.bet-input-home').prop('disabled', true);
                   else
                      $('.bet-input-home').prop('disabled', false);
                });
                $('.bet-input-home').on('input', function() {
                   if($(this).val().length)
                      $('.bet-input-away').prop('disabled', true);
                   else
                      $('.bet-input-away').prop('disabled', false);
                });



$('.wrapper').on('click', '.bet-button', function() {
  var self = $(this);
  var gameId = self.attr('gameid');
  var awayVal = $('#' + gameId + ' input[name=betAmountAway]').val();
  var homeVal = $('#' + gameId + ' input[name=betAmountHome]').val();
  var awayId = $('#' + gameId + ' .bet-input-away').data('away-id');
  var homeId = $('#' + gameId + ' .bet-input-home').data('home-id');
  var value = awayVal || homeVal;
  var id, value;

  // If the awayVal is set, assign away info to id and value variables
  if (awayVal) {
    id = awayId;
    value = awayVal;
  }
  // If the homeVal is set, assign home info to id and value variables
  if (homeVal) {
    id = homeId;
    value = homeVal;
  }
  // If there is the possibility that none of the values (awayVal or homeVal) is set and the user can execute you need to check if they are valid
  if (!value) {
    alert('please enter a value!')
  } else {
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://--------.islandshore.net/dbdata/bet/new/1/" + gameId + "/" + id + "/" + value + "",
      type: "get",
      success: function(response) {
        $('#' + gameId + ' input[name=betAmountHome]').val(''); //This resets the value box
        $('#' + gameId + ' input[name=betAmountAway]').val(''); //This resets the value box
        console.log("https://---------.islandshore.net/dbdata/bet/new/1/" + gameId + "/" + id + "/" + value + "");
      },
      error: function(xhr) {
        console.log('xhr')
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Please include a [mcve] with your question - (right now it's missing the HTML) - For starters, you could have a look at the values found in your `response` - then you can update your HTML with it.

Comment: The only thing in my response is "true"

Comment: Then what number are you talking about?

Comment: Then you will need to modify your JSON response with the values you need to display on the UI (i.e. page)

Comment: @ochi I added to my code, maybe this will help?

Comment: do you have the ability to modify the creating of the JSON response?

Comment: @ochi I'm not sure what you mean by that could you explain?

Comment: when user clicks, you send the value(s) to a URL, then you get a response - are you the creator of the response as well?

Comment: @ochi, I can see the updated JSON if that is what you mean....I can hopefully create a response.

Answer (score 1):

Data you are sending to url which updates your JSON page with the current number, You can use this data as response to the current page.
This response will be reflect to your ajax call, 
success : function(**data**).
Use this **data** to reflect changes into your HTML page.
Just see an example

*At You url (Server side)*

```
//Receive request data
//Make changes into database
//response with same data
```

*At Ajax*

```
success: function(data) {
   $('#' + gameId + ' input[name=betAmountHome]').val(data.betAmountHome);
    $('#' + gameId + ' input[name=betAmountAway]').val(data.betAmountAway); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/*first ask the server for JSON again to get the updated version*/
$.getJSON(url, function(res){
    /* 
     * Choose only the element in your UI which you would like to update
     * empty it and append the new content to it (this can be done in various 
     * ways of course .
     */
    $("divDisplayingNumber").empty().append(res.whereNumberIs);

});
```

Comment: Ok that is what I thought but isn't this going to be slow? Is this the proper way to do it?